# How to pass parameter through button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a databinding : all rows are generated depending on ItemSource. I have also add a column at the end containing a button. How to bind a field from current itemSource, as a parameter of button click event?

Here is code sample :

**WEBFORM**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    ItemType="ServiceMonitoring.MyClass" 
    SelectMethod="GetMyClassItems" 
    CellPadding="4" 
    ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MyProperty" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument='<%= MyClass.MyProperty %>' 
                    CommandName="ThisBtnClick" 
                    OnClick="Unnamed_Click" 
                    Text="retraiter !" />
                <%--<button onclick="UpdateMyClassItems" runat="server" value="VALEUR">retraiter !</button>--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class WebForm1: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    public List<MyClass> GetMyClassItems()
    {
        var a = new MyClass() { MyProperty = 2 };
        return new List<MyClass>() { a };
    }

    protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var arg = (sender as Button).CommandArgument;
        string ID = arg.ToString();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Command argument binding doesn't work. Can you help me please ?

Comment: @Aristos I have this error now : Message d'erreur du compilateur: CS0103: Le nom 'MyClass' n'existe pas dans le contexte actuel (The name 'MyClass' doesn't exist in the current context) Can you help me please?

Comment: error in English please

Comment: @naveen The name 'MyClass' doesn't exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `CommandArgument` like this.

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MyProperty") %>'
```

that will do. You are already mentioning your `ItemType="ServiceMonitoring.MyClass"`